# zip code + 4 mail merge treated like an arithmetic expression

Tags: ms-word, excel-formula, mailmerge

I'm trying to do a simple mail merge in Word 2010 but when I insert an excel field that's supposed to represent a zip code from Connecticut (ie. 06880) I am having 2 problems:

1. the leading zero gets suppressed such as 06880 becoming 6880 instead.  I know that I can at least toggle field code to make it so it works as {MERGEFIELD ZipCode # 00000} and that at least works.

but here's the real problem I can't seem to figure out:

1. A zip+4 field such as 06470-5530 gets treated like an arithmetic expression.  6470 - 5530 = 940 so by using above formula instead it becomes 00940 which is wrong.

Perhaps is there something in my excel spreadsheet or an option in Word that I need to set to make this properly work?  Please advise, thanks.

Comment: Set the format of the cell to text before the data are loaded (right mouse button -> format cell-> text)

Comment: You really should show the code/macros you are using for the problematic merge.

Answer (score 1):

See [macropod's post in this conversation](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/mail-merge-does-not-print-leading-zero-in-zip-code/0071f3a7-c7e1-4c59-9909-3690c5f1d2bc?page=1)

As long as the ZIP codes are reaching Word (with or without "-" signs in the 5+4 format ZIPs, his field code should sort things out. However, if you are mixing text and numeric formats in your Excel column, there is a danger that the OLE DB provider or ODBC driver - if that is what you are using to get the data - will treat the column as numeric and return all the text values as 0.

Yes, Word sometimes treats text strings as numeric expressions as you have noticed. It will do that when you try to apply a numeric format, or when you try to do a calculation in an { = } field, when you sum table cell contents in an { = } field, or when Word decides to do a numeric comparison in (say) an { IF } field - in the latter case you can get Word to treat the expression as a string by surrounding the comparands by double-quotes.

Answer (score 0):

in Excel, to force the string data type when entering data that looks like a number, a date, a fraction etc. but is not numeric (zip, phone number, etc.) simply type an apostrophe before the data.

`=06470` will be interpreted as a the number 6470 but `='06470` will be the string "06470"

Comment: In the general case, this isn't enough to solve the problem, unless the user is connecting to Excel using DDE. Why? When Word gets data from Excel via OLE DB (the default in Windows Word 2002 and later), or ODBC, the OLE DB provider/ODBC driver determines a data type for each column in the data source based on the first 8 (by default) cells in the column. So if your first 8 cells contain ZIP codes that have been entered as numbers, the provider/driver will treat the column as numeric. Text values in the column will come through to Word as 0. So '06470 will be treated as 0. So not so "simply"!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest fix I've found is to save the Excel file as CSV. Word takes it all at face value then.